# what can cause that git is disabled in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The git functions in VS code stopped working this morning.

I do not remember having changed anything and cannot find any settings which enable/disable git.

What else can I check?

Comment: it checks for a `.git` folder within the folder you have opened in VSCode, make sure you have that folder for git tracking

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by the comment from @tHeSiD it is crucial to have the `.git` folder present. I had this already checked.

What was wrong? I had a corrupted `.git` folder. I could do some minimal operations with `git` (in `git gui`) but when I went into some history, I got an error message informing me about the corruption.

After I had cloned the `.git` folder from the `origin`, VScode did again show the git options. Obviously, VScode had noticed the corruption.

An error message from VScode would have been very helpful!